# JAXB split single attribute and bind to multiple fields

Tags: java, xml, datetime, jaxb

Is there a way using JAXB to unmarshal/split a single attribute into multiple fields?

I have an element in a XML file that has a time attribute (XML file cannot be changed).  The precision of the time attribute is to microseconds.  Therefore I cannot store the attribute in a java Date or Joda DateTime field.

I want to store the attribute in a simple custom DateTime class where the subseconds are stored in an Integer and the rest in a java Date (I don't have access to Joda).  However, I've been unable to figure out how to unmarshal the single attribute to both the Date and Integer.

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <root>
        <Range start="2001-01-01 01:23:45.012345"/>
    </root>
```

Simple custom DateTime class:

```
public class DateTime {
    Date date;
    Integer subseconds;

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getSubseconds() {
        return this.subseconds;
    }
    public void setSubseconds(Integer subseconds) {
        this.subseconds = subseconds;
    }
}
```

**Final Solution**

Created DateTimeAdapter class as suggested by @Blaise Doughan:

```
public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {
    @Override
    public String marshal (DateTime v) {
        return v.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal (String v) {
        return new DateTime(v);
    }
}
```

Updated custom `DateTime` class (added constructor and made it immutable):

```
public class DateTime {
    Date date = new Date();
    Integer subseconds = 0;

    public DateTime(String dateString) {
        if (dateString.matches("^\\d{4}-{\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d+") {
            try {
                this.date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateString.substring(0, 19));
            }
            catch (ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.subseconds = Integer.valueOf(dateString.substring(20));
        }
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public Integer getSubseconds() {
        return this.subseconds;
    }

    ...additional methods...
}
```

I chose to do the string translation in the custom `DateTime` class constructor instead of the `XmlAdapter` so that I could use `DateTime` in other areas besides just unmarshalling.

Reference to adapter was as below:

```
    @XmlAttribute(name = "start")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
    private DateTime range;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could leverage an `XmlAdapter`.  Your `XmlAdapter` would be responsible for converting your instance of `DateTime` to/from a `String`.

```
public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {
    ...
}
```

Then you would reference the `XmlAdapter` using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation on the property of type `DateTime`.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
public DateTime getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the `XmlAdapter` direction.  Adding my detailed final solution to the bottom of my question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] dt=start.split(".");
String timeStr=dt[0];
String subsStr=dt.length>1?dt[1]:null;
```